# Who named it the Snake Lemma?

Tags: ho.history-overview, ac.commutative-algebra, kt.k-theory-and-homology

What is the history behind the colorful name of this result? Cartan-Eilenberg states it without any particular fanfare.

Comment: Jill Clayburgh. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=etbcKWEKnvg  

Comment: Very nice, Andrew!

Comment: Nice, but the tikz-rendering of page 8 of http://www.jmilne.org/not/Mtikz.pdf seems to be even a bit more snaky (and was one of the reasons I switched to tikz). 

Comment: Oh, 4 votes to close !!! I don't see any reason why this interesting question should be closed. I think there are to many easy-closers
around. 

Comment: @Lennart: but i think Andrew's drawing looks more elegant :-)

Comment: My personal favorite: math.wayne.edu/~mike/SnakeLemma.pdf I am biased though. He used xy.

Comment: @Andrew Stacy. Except for the line thickness, the color, and the "snake", which are totally different from your diagram, the code in the linked document is very standard tikz code, so I don't understand the point of your last comment. Incidentally, your diagram is very similar to the original "diagramme du serpent" in Bourbaki 1961, and so illustrates how to get a classical diagram in tikz, whereas the other diagram illustrates what is possible in tikz (which, after all, is the point of the document).

Comment: @Andrew Stacey. Sorry, I still don't understand the point of your post. And the implementation of how to fix the slanting arrows was already in the linked document long before you posted your diagram.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I suspect the name just arose naturally (for obvious reasons) but that it would be tough to trace back to any single person. After Cartan-Eilenberg proved it in 1956 (Homological Algebra, p.40) the first mention I see in English is by Tate in 1966/67 (p-divisible groups, p.178) followed by Hartshorne in 1968 (Cohomological Dimension of Algebraic Varieties, p.446), neither of which bother with a citation, reference, or quotation marks ([1](http://tinyurl.com/8h59j7o)). However, it was used a bit earlier - also without citation or quotation marks - by Begueri-Poitou in 1965 ([2](http://tinyurl.com/9aoxzl7)) as 'lemme du serpent'; mentioned early on in their abstract. [NB: the first page of the linked pdf incorrectly lists the second author's surname as Poiton.]

---

**Edit:** I used [numdam](http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/search) to search for 'serpent'. Cartan has an unrelated [quotation](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/SB/SB_1964-1966__9_/SB_1964-1966__9__271_0/SB_1964-1966__9__271_0.pdf) about a snake nearly biting its own tail (1965, pdf p.16/17), but actually relevant is a [paper](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/PMIHES/PMIHES_1964__20_/PMIHES_1964__20__5_0/PMIHES_1964__20__5_0.pdf) by Grothendieck dating to 1964 mentioning a *snake diagram* ("le diagramme du serpent", pdf p.195/258) that he attributes to (Bourbaki, *Alg. comm*, chap. I, $\S$1, no 4, prop. 2). You can see the term *snake diagram* in the much later [English translation](http://books.google.com/books?id=Bb30CjGW7EAC&lpg=PA21&vq=snake&pg=PA4#v=onepage&q&f=true), and (confirmed by the comments below) it is found in the 1961 original, as well. As far as I know, this is the first published instance that uses the *snake* terminology.

**My guess for the time being:** The term *snake diagram* originated (in French) around 1961 and was first used by one of the Bourbaki members (possibly Cartan, Eilenberg, or Grothendieck). *Snake lemma* almost certainly has a similar origin.

Comment: For what it's worth: the English version of Bourbaki dates from 1981, but the Russian translation from 1971 uses the name "snake diagram" ("змеевидная диаграмма").

Comment: I confirm that the original edition of *Algèbre commutative*, Chap. 1 dates back from 1961. For the list of Bourbaki's original editions, see www.iecn.u-nancy.fr/~eguether/archives/elements.pdf

Comment: And I confirm that the relevant pages of said french first edition look (up to language) as the english ones linked above. In particular, they mention "le diagramme de serpent".

Comment: About the Cartan quotation : the french expression equivalent to "vicious circle" is about a snake biting its own tail -- so it has nothing to do with the snake's lemma.

Answer (score 2):

If you Google for "diagramme du serpent" it becomes plausible that it was a diagram in Cartan-Eilenberg first of all, before a lemma. Interesting example of how Bourbaki became the standard grad student syllabus.